# How should I start a new JavaScript project (Testing, Developing, Building)?

Tags: javascript, build-process, project

I've developing JavaScript since many years but have never really thought about the whole testing, developing and building stuff - but I realized it's pretty much necessary. We've just used a Subversion repository with simple release tagging (switching to git soon). As a new bigger pure JavaScript project (using jQuery) is arriving soon, I'd like to optimize the whole process.

I already did some research but never found a good starting tutorial.

It's definetly a good idea to split classes and separate code blocks into several js-files and not a big one (as Prototype or jQuery do it). These js-files must be "build" into a single file. How do I achieve that?

It's pretty much necessary to Unit-test the stuff me and my colleagues are coding. I found the [js-test-driver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) which has an eclipse plugin that seems to be doing his job quite good. If my developer-folder contains all these src- and src-test-files, how do I integrate this in the building process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer part of your question:

> These js-files must be "build" into a
>   single file.

This is possible only with server side language - in ASP.NET you have built in tools for that, otherwise build your own "merger" server side file and reference that file instead of the actual .js files.

Comment: Ok, server side building is no problem - but which kind of "building" software is good for JavaScript projects? I came across Apache Ant and Rake, but honestly I don't really know, if any of them are convenient.

Comment: @amce what I mean is simple page e.g. `merger.php?files=myfile1,myfile2` that will read the contents of the given files from disk and write back to the browser. Nothing fancy here. :-)

Comment: Ok, I see :-) Maybe it's really just quite enough to write an own merging-script that may also include some optimizing like the YUI Compressor.

Answer (score 2):

For testing, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809/javascript-unit-testing

Answer (score 2):

For merging all of your JavaScript into one file you can use something like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).  You need to be looking for a minimizer first, compression second.  A minimizer just takes the files and merges them together and gets rid of whitespace.  A compressor will actually try to optimize the js for you by changing variable names and removing unnecessary code.

As for unit testing I am unsure of how you will want to do that.  There are a few unit test libraries out there.  A popular tool for testing is Selenium.  I don't currently do unit testing so I am out of my element there..

For setting up your code you could always look at using a JavaScript framework like ExtJS or JavaScriptMVC.  Those help you with setting up your code in the proper way and also helps focus your team on the proper standards and coding structure while also writing a lot of the code for you so you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

EDIT: Just a quick after thought.  Even if you don't want to use a JavaScript framework, I would suggest checking them out, especially ExtJS, just to see how they organize their code and some of the tricks they do to keep it clean.

Comment: Yes, I already looked into some JavaScript-projects for tricks (Prototype, TinyMCE).

Comment: @acme: Prototype is technically a JavaScript library, not a framework.  The difference being that Prototype was built to bundle together helper features to make programming JavaScript easier whereas ExtJS is a JavaScript framework, and is created to build complete JavaScript applications.  ExtJS takes advantage of things like Model View Controller architecture, Namespaces, and extend/overriding of classes.  Prototype, jQuery, Mootools and Dojo are great libraries, but they are just that, libraries.

Answer (score 1):

> These js-files must be "build" into a single file. How do I achieve that?

Definitely keep your files separate in version control, and only merge them during the build process.

The [YUI compressor mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377997/how-should-i-start-a-new-javascript-project-testing-developing-building/4378108#4378108) is a java-based tool that will not only merge but -- of course! -- compress your files for faster download.

If you just want a simple merge of files, a simple Perl or bash-script (or other preferred scripting language) could concatenate multiple `.js` files into one for release -- just make sure that the build script also updates all HTML in the release to reference only the single page.